# How to pass Extra Context Into Django Rest Serializer from View

Tags: python, django, serialization

I'm using Django REST Framework to overide the get_serializer_context() method in my view class, below (view.py) so I can pass an extra context variable to my serializer below (serializer.py), but I'm receiving a null value when a view my API results in the browser.  My results are below (result).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

view.py

```
class TaskListMixin(object):
    s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=1)
    r1 = Room.objects.get(pk=2)
    sp1 = r1.spacetype.pk
    s = Space.objects.get(pk = sp1)
    queryset = s.task.all()
    serializer_class = SimpleSerializer3
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


class TaskListViewSet(TaskListMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(TaskListViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        return {'request' : 'test'}
```

serializer.py

```
class SimpleSerializer3(BulkSerializerMixin, ModelSerializer):


is_my_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_is_my_object(self, obj):
    test_me = self.context.get('request')


class Meta(object):
    model = Task
    list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
    fields = ('pk','task_name', 'is_my_object')
```

results

```
[
{
    "pk": 1,
    "task_name": "Remove large debris from floor",
    "is_my_object": null
},
{
    "pk": 2,
    "task_name": "Clean walls and horizontal surfaces",
    "is_my_object": null
},
{
    "pk": 3,
    "task_name": "Clean touch points",
    "is_my_object": null
},
{
    "pk": 4,
    "task_name": "Empty trash container",
    "is_my_object": null
},
{
    "pk": 6,
    "task_name": "Spot clean desks/furniture",
    "is_my_object": null
},
{
    "pk": 7,
    "task_name": "High/Low dust",
    "is_my_object": null
}
]
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this at all? If yes, please share how you resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting your view context but no returning it with the update.

```
   def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(TaskListViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({'request' : 'test'})
        return context
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue.  I did not return the value from get_is_my_object(self, obj)

```
def get_first_name(self, obj):
    test_me = self.context.get('request')
    return test_me
```